# Append data frame issue

Tags: python, dataframe, append, concatenation

data frame issue

| ID | C1 | C2 | M1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | X |
| 2 |  | A | Y |
| 3 | C |  | W |
| 4 | G | H | Z |

result wanted

| ID | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |
| 4 | G |

The main problem is the first dataset today has C1 and C2
tomorrow we could have C1 , C2 , C3 ...Cn
the filename will be provided and my task is read it and get the result regardless of how many C related columns the file may have. column: M1 is not needed.

-----what I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv (r"C:\Users\JIRAdata_TEST.csv") 

df = df.filter(regex='ID|C')
print(df2)
```

will return all ID and C related columns, and remove the M1 column as part of data clean up--dont know if that helps.

then...am stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
In [1295]: x = df.filter(regex='ID|C').melt('ID', value_name='C').sort_values('ID').dropna().drop('variable', 1)

In [1296]: x
Out[1296]: 
   ID  C
0   1  A
4   1  B
5   2  A
2   3  C
3   4  G
7   4  H
```

Comment: you are a genius